# how to iterate all array element starting from a random index

Tags: arrays, iteration, design-patterns

I was wondering if is it possible to iterate trough all arrays elements starting from any of its elements without pre-sorting the array.

just to be clearer suppose i have the array of 5 elements:

0 1 2 3 4

i want to read all elements starting from one of their index like:

2 3 4 0 1

or

4 0 1 2 3

the idea is to keep the element order in this way:

*n ,n+1 ,..., end ,start, ..., n-1*

One solution could be (pseudocode):

```
int startElement;
int value;
for(startElement;startElement<array.count;startElement++){
  value = array[startElement];
}
for(int n = 0; n<startElement;n++){
  value = array[n];
}
```

but I don't know if there's a better one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator:

```
int start = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    value = array[(start + i) % count];
}
```

Comment: I see problem with above code. This will start from 1st element in array if size of Array is 3, But we actually want to start it from 3rd element in array.

Comment: @YoK, you'll have to decide whether you're counting 0-indexed or 1-indexed. The code above actually says start at the **4th** element, since `start = 0` represents starting at the first element. And for an array of size 3, the 4th element is the first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Try this:

```
int index = arc4rand() % count; // picks an index 0 to 4 if count is 5
// iterate through total number of elements in array
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    // if element 4 go back to zero
    if (index == count-1) { index = 0; }
    //do something here
    someValue = yourArray[index];
}
```

EDIT: When I first answered this I thought you were asking about picking the random index. I probably misunderstood. I also use the modulus operator to iterate arrays as in the first answer, and that's probably the more elegant approach. You can also use the if statement above, so I'll leave my answer here as an alternate.